# Composer update or install issue

Tags: laravel, terminal, composer-php, cpanel

I have an web application which successfully run since august 2020. now i want to add milon barcode package and it successfully ok in local server that's why i need to run coposer install or update command in cpanel terminal. but there show some problem.

**N.B Laravel version 5.8, composer version 2.0.6, php version 7.4.**

when i try to run composer install it show [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OP2BJ.png)

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ErrorException: proc_open(): unable to create pipe Too many open files in phar:///opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:952

when try to run [composer update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OP2BJ.png)

Failed to download phpoption/phpoption from dist: getaddrinfo() thread failed to start

when try to run [composer self-update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58Kch.png)

[Composer\Downloader\FilesystemException]
Filesystem exception:
Composer update failed: "/opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer" could not be written.
rename(/opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Comment: Please share more details, like the error messages in text form and your attempts to resolve the problem. "Too many open files" looks like a problem with your system - can you share more details about that? Why not run `composer install`  through your deployment process, such that you don't even have to install Composer on the production system after all?

Comment: [Please do not post images of code/error messages.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557).

Comment: in local server i wast installed milon/barcode package for generate barcode. in live server/cpanel i pulled the and run {composer update}  to activate this package. but i didn't finish and show some error

Comment: "*Too many open files*" and "*getaddrinfo() thread failed to start*" - these sound like OS or hardware problems, not related to PHP or composer.  Can you reboot the machine and try again?  Maybe a question for your hosing provider.

Comment: `composer update`  won't activate any package, it will even change the versions listed in `composer.lock` such that you can not be sure that you've tested your code against the same package versions you use in production

Comment: the previous day composer update worked fine. but now it show the problem. composer install is not work also. please check upper portion which mention in the question

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable **proc_open**
Please Follow the Instruction Below in cPanel

```
Software > MultiPHP INI Editor > Editor Mode
```

Select your PHP version and search for (**disable_functions**)

```
disable_functions = "proc_open,..., ..."
```

Now remove (**proc_open**) from the list and save.

Otherwise, contact your hosting service provider to enable **proc_open**.

Answer (score -1):

try using this command

```
composer update --no-scripts
```

Comment: same error 'Failed to download symfony/css-selector from dist: getaddrinfo() thread failed to start.'